Sharepoint 2013 add button to editform
I have a form in SP2013 I want to be able to export to pdf. For this I create an extra button in the ribbon. Now I get an error 'unable to get property parentnode or undefined or null reference.

var linkButton = '<span class="ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer" unselectable="on"><span class=" ms-cui-img-32by32 ms-cui-img-cont-float ms-cui-imageDisabled" unselectable="on">'
+'<img class="" style="top: -102px;left: -408px;"unselectable="on" src="/_layouts/15/1033/images/formatmap32x32.png?rev=40"></span></span>'
+'<span class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel" unselectable="on">Maak<br>PDF</span>';

    var editLink = document.getElementById("Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem-Large");
    var node = document.createElement("A");
    node.text = "Print Item";
    node.className = "ms-cui-ctl-large";
    node.innerHTML = linkButton;
    node.onclick = function() {
        printTable(this);
        return false;
    };
    editLink.parentNode.appendChild(node);

});```
On another system my code worked.

